How to combine slice assignment, mask assignment and broadcasting in PyTorch?
To be more specific, I'm wondering how to assign a tensor by slice and by mask at different dimension(s) simultaneously in PyTorch.
Here's a small example about what I want to do:
With the tensors and masks below:
x = torch.zeros(2, 3, 4, 6)
mask = torch.tensor([[ True, True, False], [True, False, True]])
y = torch.rand(2, 3, 1, 3)

I want to achieve something like
x[mask, :, :3] = y[mask]


In dimension 0 and 1, only the 4x6/1x3 slices in x/y that whose corresponding element in mask is True are allowed to be assigned.
In dimension 2, I hope the 1-row tensor in y can be broadcast to all the 8 rows of x,
In dimension 3, only the first 3 elements in x are assigned with the 3-element tensor from y.

However, with code above, following error was caught:
RuntimeError: shape mismatch: value tensor of shape [4, 1, 3] cannot be broadcast to indexing result of shape [4, 3, 6]

It seems that PyTorch did [mask] indexing instead, and ignored the :3 indexing.
I've also tried
x[mask][:, :, :3] = y[mask]

No error occurred but the assignment still failed.
I know I can assign by slice and by mask step by step, but I hope to avoid any intermediate tensors if possible.
Tensors in neural networks may be extremely big, so may be an all-in-one assignment may take less time and less memory.

You can do the following:
x = torch.zeros(2, 3, 4, 6)
mask = torch.tensor([[ True, True, False], [True, False, True]])
y = torch.rand(2, 3, 1, 3)
x[..., :3][mask] = y[mask]

This produces the same result as
i, j = mask.nonzero(as_tuple = True)
x[i, j, :, :3] = y[i, j]

For the 2D mask scenario. This method also works for additional dims:
x = torch.zeros(2, 3, 3, 4, 6)
y = torch.rand(2, 3, 3, 1, 3)
mask = torch.rand(2,3,3)>0.5
x[..., :3][mask] = y[mask]

For additional dims, the only constraint is that the first n=mask.ndim dims of x and y must match the shape of mask and the final dimension of y is 3 to match the :3.

That solution seems great, but I'm wondering if x[..., :3] will create a intermediate tensor or just a "tensor of references"?

The ellipsis indexing syntax returns a view just like all slicing. However, indexing with [mask] creates a copy (this is the case for all indexing with boolean arrays). You can verify this by checking x.data_ptr(), x[..., :3].data_ptr(), x[mask].data_ptr(), x[..., :3][mask].data_ptr(). x and x[..., :3] will have the same data pointer while both [mask] indexing variants will have different data pointers as boolean array indexing returns a copy rather than a view.

I think I've found a solution, though it is not as convenient as direct indexing:
i, j = mask.nonzero(as_tuple = True)
x[i, j, :, :3] = y[i, j]

However, in the situation that the shape of the masked dimensions are unknown, an additional reshaping will be involved to squeeze the unknown dimensions in one, which still causes extra time and memory.
So I still think that it is nonsense that mask and slice assignment cannot be used simultaneously.
